# got undefined variable in php code

Tags: php, variables

I got a error message when I run my php

however the result is come out

this is my code

```
function cart() {
    foreach($_SESSION as $name => $value) {
        if ($value>0) {
            if (substr($name, 0, 5) == 'cart_'){
                $id = substr($name, 5, (strlen($name)-5));
                $get = mysql_query('SELECT id, name, price FROM products WHERE id=' .mysql_real_escape_string((int)$id));
                while ($get_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($get)){
                    $sub = $get_row['price'] * $value;
                    echo $get_row['name'].' x '.$value.' @ &pound'.number_format($get_row['price'], 2).' = &pound'.number_format($sub, 2).' <a href="cart.php?remove='.$id.'">[-]</a> <a href="cart.php?add='.$id.'">[+]</a> <a href="cart.php?delete='.$id.'">[Delete]</a><br />' ;
                }
            }
            $total += $sub;
        }
    }
    echo $total;
}
?>
```

I got a error message

```
 Notice: Undefined variable: total in C:\xampp\htdocs\shoppingcart\cart.php on line 54
```

which line 54 is

```
 echo $total;
```

what's wrong with my code??

I think I have defined the code in

```
 $total += $sub;
```

thanks for helping me :)

Comment: You haven't initialized your `$total` variable. Put `$total = 0;` before the loop.

Comment: REFER [EXISTING QUESTION LINK HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index)

Comment: @THANGA Don't shout please. Writing in all caps is considered shouting on the net.

Comment: Certainly not @Baz,  will avoid the caps in future

Answer (score 2):

To use a `+=` it needs to be set first, else you get the warning.

Pop a `$total=0;` above it and you should be sweet.

```
function cart() {
    $total=0;
    // rest of your code...
```

You can read further about assignment operators [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.assignment.php).

Answer (score 2):

If your `$_SESSION` is empty, the variable is never initialized, for example. Also, the operator `+=` means add something to the variable - which triggers a notice if the variable is not set beforehand.

You could put `$total = 0;` before your loop:

```
$total = 0;
foreach($_SESSION as $name => $value) {
...
```

It's a good practice anyways to **always initialize your variables**, so you can save yourself from some bad surprises.

Answer (score 1):

Add this as the first line of your function:

```
$total = 0;
```

Because now the first time your loop runs, $total is not a known var